# Return documents where field value is either 1 or 3

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

suppose I have the following documents

```
{Person_ID : 1, name : 'Joe'}
{Person_ID : 3, name : 'Mike'}
{Person_ID : 10, name : 'Nick'}
{Person_ID : 20, name : 'Larry'}
```

I would like to query for Person_ID 1 and 3, how do I go about it? I tried this, but doesn't work:

```
DB.find({'Person_ID': [1, 3]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$in` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#in):

```
DB.find({'Person_ID': {'$in': [1, 3]}})
```

According to the MongoDB documentation:

> The `$in` operator selects the documents where the value of a field
>   equals any value in the specified array. To specify an $in expression, use the following prototype:
>   ...
>
> ```
> { field: { $in: [<value1>, <value2>, ... <valueN> ] } }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The `$in` query operator does exactly what you want.

```
DB.find({'Person_ID': {'$in' : [1,3]}})
```